# overlayMapTypes in react-native-map

Tags: javascript

1. image repeat
2. not working properly
3. url tiles are server side images
4. same image show onw than 100 times
   this code is web, how can implement in react-native and i am use react-native-map

<UrlTile
maximumZ={
18
}
minimumZ={
20
}
tileSize={256}
urlTemplate={imageUrl}
opacity={1.0}
zIndex={-1}
tileCacheMaxAge={20}
doubleTileSize={true}
flipY={false}
/>

```
/**
 * @license
 * Copyright 2019 Google LLC. All Rights Reserved.
 * SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
 */
function initMap() {
  const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    zoom: 18,
    center: { lat: 37.783, lng: -122.403 },
  });
  const bounds = {
    17: [
      [20969, 20970],
      [50657, 50658],
    ],
    18: [
      [41939, 41940],
      [101315, 101317],
    ],
    19: [
      [83878, 83881],
      [202631, 202634],
    ],
    20: [
      [167757, 167763],
      [405263, 405269],
    ],
  };
  const imageMapType = new google.maps.ImageMapType({
    getTileUrl: function (coord, zoom) {

      console.log("coord",coord)
      return [
        "https://www.gstatic.com/io2010maps/tiles/5/L2_",
        zoom,
        "_",
        coord.x,
        "_",
        coord.y,
        ".png",
      ].join("");
    },
    tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
  });
//cosonle.log("imageMapType",imageMapType)
  map.overlayMapTypes.push(imageMapType);
}

window.initMap = initMap;
```

plese provied an anwser urlTiles in react-native using react-native-map

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
how can use this code
import {UrlTile} from 'react-native-maps';

<MapView region={this.state.region} onRegionChange={this.onRegionChange}>
  <UrlTile
    /**
     * The url template of the tile server. The patterns {x} {y} {z} will be replaced at runtime
     * For example, http://c.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png
     */
    urlTemplate={this.state.urlTemplate}
    /**
     * The maximum zoom level for this tile overlay. Corresponds to the maximumZ setting in
     * MKTileOverlay. iOS only.
     */
    maximumZ={19}
    /**
     * flipY allows tiles with inverted y coordinates (origin at bottom left of map)
     * to be used. Its default value is false.
     */
    flipY={false}
  />
</MapView>;
```